# Wrapping more than one static error to use with errors.Is

Tags: go

[Go 1.13](https://blog.golang.org/go1.13-errors) introduced the [errors.Is](https://golang.org/pkg/errors/#Is) function to check if an error contains a target error in its chain:

```
err := fmt.Errorf("access denied: %w", ErrPermission)
...
if errors.Is(err, ErrPermission) ...
```

At this point it is noted that `fmt.Errorf` only takes **one** `%w` directive.

Now consider multiple levels of errors:

Level One:

```
ErrUnexpectedEOF        = errors.New("unexpected EOF")
ErrRequiredFieldMissing = errors.New("required field missing")
ErrValueOutOfRange      = errors.New("value out of range")
```

Level Two:

```
ErrParse = errors.New("parse error")
```

For the purpose of this question I'll leave it at two levels, but note that there could be `n` levels.

How can a level one and a level two error be chained so that `errors.Is` returns `true` if used against the level two or the wrapped level one error?

Comment: Have you checked https://github.com/g8rswimmer/error-chain?

Comment: Interesting. That is definitely along the lines I'm thinking. I'm a bit confused by why this isn't part of the standard library, or why I can't find more chatter about this topic online...I mean even this error-chain library you just pointed me to doesn't exactly scream "popular".

Comment: Added an answer just in case someone else looks for this.

Comment: Also worth looking at Dave Cheney's error package - see his blog - https://dave.cheney.net/2016/04/27/dont-just-check-errors-handle-them-gracefully

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The rationale behind `fmt.Errorf` is to create error hierarchies in which each error has a single parent (or is the root of the hierarchy).

```golang
type errorOne struct{}

func (e errorOne) Error() string {
    return "Error One happended"
}

...
    e1 := errorOne{}
    e2 := fmt.Errorf("E2: %w", e1)
    e3 := fmt.Errorf("E3: %w", e2)
```

You can check if an error wraps another using `errors.Is`

If you want to have "multiple parents" for an error then you can use [error-chain](https://github.com/g8rswimmer/error-chain). It creates a custom `ErrorChain` type that handles this case.

Taking an example from the package Github page

```golang
type myError struct {
    code int
}

func (e *myError) Error() string {
    return fmt.Sprintf("%d", e.code)
}

func (e *myError) Is(target error) bool {
    te, ok := target.(*myError)
    if ok == false {
        return false
    }
    return e.code == te.code
}

....

    ec := chain.New()
    ec.Add(errors.New("some error"))
    ec.Add(fmt.Errorf("wrap it up %w", &myError{code: 12}))
```

Comment: I have accepted this answer since it directly answers my question. It appears though that after reading Dave Cheney's blog (linked by Inian in his comment above), that it's not advisable for packages to export errors as values.

Answer (score 1):

In Go 1.20, it is now possible to wrap multiple errors via `Join` function and `Errorf` now also accepts multiple `%w` arguments. In 1.19 version or older this would lead to runtime panic:

```
err1 := errors.New("err1")
err2 := errors.New("err2")


err := fmt.Errorf("%w + %w", err1, err2)
err = errors.Join(err1, err2)
```

For more info: https://lukas.zapletalovi.com/posts/2022/wrapping-multiple-errors/